# Cannot use order by in this select?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have this query..

```
SELECT ClassId, Sum(TeachersCount) as NumCount
FROM ClassSubject 
GROUP BY ClassId 
ORDER BY NumCount
```

but when I run this, access pops up a box asking me the value of NumCount? But this is not a parameter, this is.. well this is the sum of teachers that can teach that class, and it is to be calculated. So why is access asking me for its (`NumCount's`) value?

What I want is to count the number of teacher in a class and order this by increasing value of teacher count, I think that's what my query does, but why is it asking me for value of `NumCount`? One more thing, if I remove this `ORDER BY` clause, it runs fine, without asking me the value of `NumCount`? So what's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

```
SELECT ClassId, Sum(TeachersCount) as NumCount 
FROM ClassSubject 
GROUP BY ClassId 
ORDER BY Sum(TeachersCount)
```

You can also ORDER BY the ordinal number, in this case 2:

```
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: Why can't I use `ORDER BY NumCount`?

Comment: You cannot order by an alias in MS Access (Jet/ACE) SQL.

Comment: @pOcHa
really? That's surprising, but anyways, if you say so, also as Remou commented I can't do it in MS Access (use alias of a column) but can I do this in SQL server 2008?

Comment: @Razort4x: All three methods (ordering by the same `SUM()` expression or referencing the column in `ORDER BY` by either its alias or its ordinal number in the `SELECT` clause) would work in SQL Server.